# How to make the map wait till the current index item is finished processing and then take the next item for processing using RxJava?

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java2, rx-android, rx-kotlin2

I'm trying to convert the input streams into the file. So when user selects 1 image, it all works well. But when user selects multiple images, for example 4 then the below code is not working as expected; I see only 2 files path in Log statement.

```
compositeDisposable.add(Observable.fromIterable(inputStreamList)
                .map {
                    FileUtils.saveInputStreamToFile(it, directory, 500)
                }.toList()
                .toObservable()
                .subscribeOn(schedulerProvider.io())
                .subscribe({
                    it.forEach {file->
                        Log.d("TAG", "Path ${file.path}")
                    }
                    Log.d("TAG", "Size ${it.size}")
                }, {

                })
        )
```

Here's saveInputStreamToFile method

```
fun saveInputStreamToFile(input: InputStream, directory: File, height: Int): File? {
        val currentTime = dateFormat.format(Date())
        val imageName = "_$currentTime"
        val temp = File(directory.path + File.separator + "flab\$file\$for\$processing")
        try {
            val final = File(directory.path + File.separator + imageName + ".$IMAGE_JPG")
            val output = FileOutputStream(temp)
            try {
                val buffer = ByteArray(4 * 1024) // or other buffer size
                var read: Int = input.read(buffer)
                while (read != -1) {
                    output.write(buffer, 0, read)
                    read = input.read(buffer)
                }
                output.flush()
                saveBitmap(decodeFile(temp, height)!!, final.path, IMAGE_JPG, 80)
                return final
            } finally {
                output.close()
                temp.delete()
            }
        } finally {
            input.close()
        }
    }
```

I want the next input stream to be taken only once the current input stream is converted to file. How to achieve this? Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In RX you can do something like this:

```
    Observable.fromCallable {
        return inputStreamList.map {
            FileUtils.saveInputStreamToFile(it, directory, 500)
        }.toList()

    }.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .subscribe(object : Observer<List<File>> {
            override fun onComplete() {

            }

            override fun onSubscribe(d: Disposable) {
            }

            override fun onNext(files: List<File>) {
                //here you can iterate and complete do your work
                files.forEach { file ->
                    Log.d("TAG", "Path ${file.path}")
                }
                Log.d("TAG", "Size ${files.size}")

            }

            override fun onError(e: Throwable) {
            }

        })
```

This will ensure that your work will be done synchronously in background, and you will observe your result in `onNext()` on the MainThread as specified.

Make sure you use package `io.reactivex`

EDIT:

get rid of your RX package and set these in `build.gradle`

```
implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxkotlin:2.3.0'
implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.2'
```

Comment: Do I need to change the return type of `saveInputStreamToFile` method?

Comment: not really. if it's complaining, then add ? (nullable) / or remove ? from File?

Comment: I get Type mismatch error. Required unit but found List<File?>

Comment: where are you getting it?

Comment: Sorry, that was my mistake. I corrected it. Now getting error at `subscribe` - `None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied`

Comment: it appears you're using another rx package

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212586/discussion-between-alan-deep-and-aniruddha).